# not able to download different blob file

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

i am new to adf , trying to download blob file from from mySqlDb through VO .
here  am only able to download the file that has been uploaded last not the one uploaded previously , below is my code
in this i am using 'downloadFileListener' inside a link and 'empReviewVo1Iterator' is my vo itrerator name.
even when i try to download except  last uploaded file, it downloads the last uploaded file

```
public void downloadFileListener(FacesContext facesContext, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {

    BindingContext ctx = BindingContext.getCurrent();
    DCBindingContainer bc = (DCBindingContainer) ctx.getCurrentBindingsEntry();
    DCIteratorBinding iterator = bc.findIteratorBinding("empReviewVo1Iterator");
    Row row = iterator.getCurrentRow();
    Blob review = (Blob) row.getAttribute("Reviewfile");
    String fileName = (String) row.getAttribute("Filename");
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = review.getBinaryStream();
        int fileLength = inputStream.available();
        //System.out.println("fileLength = " + fileLength);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int bytesRead = -1;

        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        inputStream.reset();
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // response.getWriter().print("SQL Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I suggest you transform your code into a MCVE (see [mCVe]) to make it easier for everyone to reproduce and inspect your problem. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is your exact goal? If you want to download all files, you have to loop using your iterator. If you want to download a specific file (but not the last one), you have to "move" your iterator, e.g. by using 'findByKey' (see http://www.baigzeeshan.com/2010/03/adf-how-to-find-rows-in-iterator.html).

Comment: i want to download specific file it may be last one or not the last one , but when ever i try to download it downloads last one my iterator is not getting the current row on click , it get the last uploaded file .